# Causes of one table being slower than other tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database on SQL Server with a few decent size tables. A few of the tables have 10 million+ records but one specifically has a lot of performance issues but no more or less columns than the others. At times I can not even select top 1000 from it without timing out.

What are the possible causes of one specific table having these types of issues? I don't think it's uncommitted transactions... This will happen however after trying to update some columns. I should be the only one using it right now. I'm not really sure what the issue is. In fact I have (effectively) a clone of this table I can use fine but after attempting to update the one I can not do anything with it.

The updates were simple coalesce updates to get rid of null values.

Comment: You need to show the execution plans if you want performance advice.

Comment: On select top 1000...?

Comment: Exec plan on the update is extremely simple it is just begin transaction --> update --.> commit.

Comment: Whatever is running slow... speed comes down to many factors, indexes,statistics, load etc.. its not a question which has a generic answer, it has a specific answer which requires investigation.

Comment: There are so many possibilities that this can't be answered, you could even have computed columns that query other tables. You need to provide much more information, a good start would be the script to create the table (with its indexes, relations, ...). On SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the table and chose Script Table as CREATE to. Also the execution plan would be helpful, you get that on SQL Server Management Studio with a right-click on the editor window where you run the query and chosing Include Actual Execution Plan.

Comment: +1 on the computed columns. It doesn't take many badly written scalar functions to kill performance for simple selects.